# How could I optimize this jquery?

Tags: jquery

I wrote some JS code to change the CSS style of one element if another is hovered. I have 6 pairs of elements. It's obvious that there is a better way to code it. Please help me. Website uses Worpdress.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.img-zink').hover(function() {
      $('#btn-zink').attr('style', 'background-color: #4aab61; color: white !important');
    }, function() {
      $('#btn-zink').attr('style', '');
    });

    $('.img-rist').hover(function() {
      $('#btn-rist').attr('style', 'background-color: #4aab61; color: white !important');
    }, function() {
      $('#btn-rist').attr('style', '');
    });

    $('.img-start').hover(function() {
      $('#btn-start').attr('style', 'background-color: #4aab61; color: white !important');
    }, function() {
      $('#btn-start').attr('style', '');
    });

    $('.img-humat').hover(function() {
      $('#btn-humat').attr('style', 'background-color: #4aab61; color: white !important');
    }, function() {
      $('#btn-humat').attr('style', '');
    });

    $('.img-bor').hover(function() {
      $('#btn-bor').attr('style', 'background-color: #4aab61; color: white !important');
    }, function() {
      $('#btn-bor').attr('style', '');
    });

  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant markup

Comment: Refactoring of working code is off topic for StackOverflow, and is on topic for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would advise using Classes instead of adjusting the element style. Also since you are performing Hover for each of them, adjust your selector to catch all the elements and apply hover just once to all of them.

Comment: @RomaQ Note that the answer you accepted is still rather brittle and there are better ways, however as stated in the other comments we would need to see the associated HTML, which for some reason you seem unwilling to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following css

```
.active {
   background-color: #4aab61;
   color: white !important;
 }
```

and then toggle the class like this for all elements in one `hover()` function:

```
 $('.img-zink, .img-rist, .img-start, .img-humat, .img-bor').hover(function() {
   let className = $(this).attr("class").substr(3);
   $('#btn' + className).toggleClass("active");
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! I just assign to variable id instead of class, because my element has more than one class.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)